# Call python gearman worker using laravel 5

Tags: php, python, laravel-5, gearman

I am using **laravel 5**. What I need is to call **python gearman worker**.

I have created a **gearman worker in python**.
And I have created a **gearman client in laravel 5**.

I have directly added gearman client code in my controller like:

```
$client = new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
$job_data = array("func_name" => "searchTweets", "query" => "query_to_search");
$result = $client->doNormal("php_twitter_worker", json_decode($job_data));
if ($result) {
    print_r($result);
}
```

But it throws error :

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\GearmanClient' not found
```

I know what is the error because I don't have GearmanClient Class in Controllers. Actually I don't know how to use it.

After doing some **R&D** , I found a package using [gearman in laravel5](https://github.com/pafelin/laravel-gearman) but not getting how to use it as Gearman Client and how it make a **call to my python gearman worker**.

Any help on this ?

Comment: Hi! Are you using composer? If yes what library have you required for Gearman? You are definitely missing a use namespace inclusion here

Comment: Yep, in laravel 5 you need to use composer to auto include the libraries you need, then, add them to providers and optionally give it an alias. You know how to do it?

Comment: @Thomas: I am using composer. But for gearman, I don't need any namespace for it. I have directly installed gearman in my lampp. Gearman works in core php directly, without using any namespace. But how to use it in laravel5.

Comment: @JuanBonnett: No, I don't know. Can you help me?

Comment: You're saying that you can instantiate GearmanClient(); in any other application with vanilla PHP, but not laravel?

Comment: @JuanBonnett: Ya. It worked in core php. How make it possible  gearman    in laravel.

Comment: Ummm... This is really new for me... You installed your custom module in PHP and worked in vanilla PHP but not in laravel.... I actually have no idea

Comment: @JuanBonnett: okay.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your class is namespaced, your controller there, PHP will look for a class inside of this namespace.

Therefore, to use a class from the root namespace, you should either use a use statement or prefix the classname with \, \ being the root namespace.

```
use GearmanClient;

$client = new \GearmanClient();
```

Use one or the other, not both, my code above is actually quite confusing...